# how to disable auto commit when run winsql command-line

Tags: sql, database, db2, winsql

I have this code in c#:

```
 string parameters = "-cDriver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=" + txtDb.Text + ";hostname=" + txtIp.Text + ";port=" + txtPort.Text + ";protocol=TCPIP;uid=" + txtUid.Text + ";pwd=" + txtPws.Text + "";

 Process myProcess = new Process();
 myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSQL\\Winsql.exe\" \"" + parameters + "\"";
 myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 myProcess.Start();
```

When the WinSql is open it is with autocommit enabled, however i need to disable.

Comment: Did you try passing the corresponding property in the connect string?

Comment: I did not find the property for that, so my question.

Comment: [AutoCommit=0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008772.html)

Comment: AutoCommit=0 Dont work